# How to read a string from starting index

Tags: vb.net, string

```
Dim text as string = "Visual Basic"

output: "Basic"
```

I need to read a string and print it but not starting at the very first index. The text may vary so I want to know if there is a way to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `IndexOf` method to find the first space, then the `SubString` method to get the part of the string after the space:

```
Dim idx As Integer = text.IndexOf(" "C);
Dim output As String = text.SubString(idx + 1);
```

(This even works if there would be no space at all in the string. Then `idx` will be `-1` (the value meaning "not found"), so `idx + 1` will be zero and `output` will be the whole string.)